# How to upload base64 encoded image data to S3 using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, heroku, canvas, amazon-s3, base64

I have a rails app on Heroku (cedar env). It has a page where I render the canvas data into an image using `toDataURL()` method. I'm trying to upload the returned base64 image data string directly to s3 using JavaScript (bypassing the server-side). The problem is that since this isn't a file, how do I upload the base64 encoded data directly to S3 and save it as a file there?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found a way to do this. After a lot of searching a looking at different tutorials.

You have to convert the Data URI to a blob and then upload that file to S3 using CORS, if you are working with multiple files I have separate XHR requests for each.

I found this function which turns your the Data URI into a blob which can then be uploaded to S3 directly using CORS ([Convert Data URI to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954337/1055838) )

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

[Here is a great tutorial on uploading directly to S3, you will need to customise the code to allow for the blob instead of files.](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/direct-browser-uploading-amazon-s3-cors-fileapi-xhr2-and-signed-puts/)

Answer (score 5):

Jamcoope's answer is very good, however the blob constructor is not supported by all browsers.  Most notably android 4.1 and android 4.3.  There are `Blob` polyfills, but `xhr.send(...)` will not work with the polyfill.  The best bet is something like this:

```
var u = dataURI.split(',')[1],
    binary = atob(u),
    array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
}

var typedArray = Uint8Array(array);

// now typedArray.buffer can be passed to xhr.send
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone cares: here is the coffescript version of the function given above!

```
  convertToBlob = (base64) ->
    binary = atob base64.split(',')[1]
    array = []
    for i in [0...binary.length]
      array.push binary.charCodeAt i
    new Blob [new Uint8Array array], {type: 'image/jpeg'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if OP has already solved this, but I'm working on a very similar feature. In doing a little research, I came across these articles that might be helpful.

- http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/25/upload-s3-files-directly-with-ajax/
- http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/01/save-an-image-file-directly-to-s3-from-a-web-browser-using-html5-and-backbone-js/