# upload canvas image to S3 server

Tags: javascript, upload, html5-canvas

Can someone please show me how to upload the canvas image using AWS JavaScript to S3 server?

I am having bit trouble in the uploading image on Amazon S3 server using JavaScript SDK and need to achieve the following things.

-> Create an image on HTML5 canvas and resize the image in the JavaScript.

-> Then upload the image to Amazon S3 server.

But the problem :

*) While uploading the image to S3 server it is uploading the image pixel information on S3 instead of image.

So, in the S3 browser preview, it is showing the image stream instead of image while using the below code.

Moreover, AWS Javascript support Body in the following formats
Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream.

Below is the code:

HTML Code

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="background-color: greenyellow;">Your browser doesn't support html5! Please download the latest version.
</canvas>
<input type="button" id="upload-button" value="Upload to S3" />

<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.4.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
        AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'ACCESSKEY', secretAccessKey: 'SECRETKEY' });
        AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-1';
        
         $(function () {
         
         $("#upload-button").click(OnUpload);    
         
         });
         
         function OnUpload(){
            
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'Images/IMG_0001.JPG';
            
            img.onload = function () {
            <!--image resize -->
             var MAX_WIDTH = 200;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 200;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                
                <!--image resize end-->
                
                var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
                var typedArray = imageData.data;
                
                var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'bucketName' } });
                var results = document.getElementById('results');
                results.innerHTML = '';
                var params = { Key: "sample.png", ContentType: "image/png", Body: typedArray };

                bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                    results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';

                });                
            }           
         }

</script>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Got it to work now, finally! using [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883871/how-to-upload-base64-encoded-image-data-to-s3-using-javascript-only]

Comment: Is the above code the latest/correct code for uploading a canvas so S3? I'm having problems doing this myself.

Comment: @Pradeep could you please share how did your file uploaded aws s3

Answer (score 13):

For people still facing issues , this will save some time :

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("imagePreviewChatFooter");
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    var blobData = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
                    var fileName = file.name;
                    var params = {Key: fileName, ContentType: file.type, Body: blobData};
                    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.');
                    });
```

AND

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I could not figure this out before I found your post.

Comment: Awesome. Making life easy. [StackOverflow General Base 64 Encoding Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)

Comment: For those wanting some context, the `dataURItoBlob` function Rahil used here comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954337/1055838

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahil Sharmas answer works great and in some ways, using a helper function is better. The canvas api actually has a built in `toBlob` method that you can call on the canvas element. I tried to use it with async await but got errors, not 100% sure but I guess you have to use callback. The signature is:

`canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, quality)`

the callback receives the blob and the mimeType and quality are option with mimeType defaulting to `image/png`

so the generic version of my implementation is:

`canvas.toBlob(blob => upload(blob), 'image/jpeg', 1.0)`

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)