# How to save an image from an HTML5 canvas and upload it to image storage?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, amazon-s3, html5-canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas image that I want to save from one page and use it on another page (by uploading the image into storage, AWS S3). I don't want to upload it to S3 on the first page.

What is the best strategy for this?

Possible solution

1. save the canvas as a dataURL / buffer ?
2. save that file to the user's device (local storage)?
3. on the new page retrieve the file
4. post image / file to S3

Comment: If you're navigating from the canvas page to the page you want to upload from, you can pass that image data to the new page on navigation. [React Router Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238733/6027891)

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567511/downloading-canvas-image-using-toblob

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upload canvas image to S3 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694629/upload-canvas-image-to-s3-server)